# Dynamical system model representation for the geometric motion of soap bubbles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, mathematical-physics, computational-physics

I have been trying to describe the dynamical system model for soap bubbles proliferating, coming into existence and moving and pushing around other bubbles (i.e. water gushing into a sink, full of dish soap). As new soap bubbles are formed, they push the existing collective around to make room for themselves. At a given time, t, a number of new bubbles enter the collective at random points on the surface $(x_i,y_i)$, (we can treat the problem as flat 2D process, with each bubble represented as circle of random radius, $r_i(t)$ and a location $(x_i(t),y_i(t))$.

Let's focus ONLY on the discrete time step dynamics (not looking at the short time transient dynamics of a soap bubble coming into existence from nothing). Assume each discrete time step represents the state of the system where a new set of bubble(s) have already appeared and settled, along with all the pre-existing bubbles, into their final radius and location for that discrete time step t. I am looking for a state space description that can describe the system at t and t+1. The figure below maybe a good one time step description of the process I am trying to capture.

[image]

One way to capture the state of the system would be through a direct encoding of the coordinates of the bubble collective, $(x,y,r)$ triplets at time $t$:  ${\bf{x}}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{3n}$, as the state vector of a discrete time dynamical system. This would work if the number of bubbles were to stay the same, but that's a very cumbersome representation in this case as the number of bubbles are constantly changing. I am trying to figure out what would be a better description of a system like this? I am only interested in the representation aspect of the problem at this stage and not the specifics of the dynamics (how the system is evolving in time). Is looking at this as a system of particles (vs. something else, i.e. a flow) the correct approach? If not, what would be a more natural modeling context and description of the process to capture a state space whose dimension ${\bf{x}} (t)$ would remain fixed while allowing (x,y,r) triplets accessible at any time t? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of something in the spirit of creation and destruction operators of quantum field theory, where a creation operator changes the state from $n$ particles to $n+1$ particles? I don't know why you would need so much formalism. I would think a set of bubbles would work. The set can grow or shrink as needed. If you are writing software, a list would be appropriate? Or am I not seeing what you are asking for?

Comment: Thank you @mmesser314.  If it was only a matter of programming there would be no issue. However, mathematical formalism is needed to put the one step time evolution into the dynamical system form: that is $x(t+1)=F(x(t))$ for autonomous dynamics or $x(t+1)=F(x(t),u(t))$ with input $u(t)$. This would allow for a host of analyses of the system such as equilibrium,  stability etc. which is the ultimate goal.  Remarkably a colleague also mentioned creation and destruction operators from quantum field theory which I know very little about. I can't help feeling there is simpler solution!

Comment: At first glance, this looks much like how [smoothed particle hydrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics) works, except those simulations tend to have constant numbers of elements. Adding/removing new bubbles should be an exercise in linked list tracking, I imagine--though how that's to be done isn't something I've yet thought of.

Comment: Thank you @Kyle, while the "linked list tracking" is a good programming strategy, it's hard for me to imagine it formalized mathematically in the context of a dynamical system, I would be very interested if you know of a way.

Comment: Well it'd be an algorithm, right? So kinda is already a formal mathematical statement, no? Also isn't what your post is asking and would probably take up too much space in comments

Comment: An algorithm works with slightly different constructs. For example if we are talking about growing lists, it's difficult to treat that as a variable that you can calculate it's derivative, or  linearize it's temporal behavior around a point etc.

Comment: I don't understand what a derivative of a list means or why it seems necessary to compute it.

Comment: I guess even a linked list isn't necessary, even a a mutable list of states of particle states would work: [particle a state, particle b state, particle c state, ...] and each state knows where in the list its close neighbors are so that forces are faster to calculate than summing over all particles & measuring distances. When a particle is replaced by $n$ more particles, you replace the one case & add $n-1$ more elements to the list, then recalculate the close neighbors lists.

Comment: In which case, there's no need for derivatives or temporal behavior of a list, it's simply a placeholder for the bubbles for computing the actual dynamics.